# Changing UIButton configuration with Objective-C doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

`contentEdgeInsets` was deprecated in iOS 15, now I am using `self.configuration.contentInsets` to set the padding of the button. But after I finished setting the configuration, I still need to call `self.configuration.contentInsets.top/bottom/leading/trailing` to calculate the `intrinsicContentSize`, but it is always return `0`. The `self.contentEdgeInsets.left/right/top/bottom` works fine, but I do not want to use it since it is already deprecated, is there other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I am using `self.configuration.contentInsets` to set the padding of the button.

You cannot alter the configuration through the property value (a pointer) which a `UIButton` already holds. Instead you should trigger a setter method, by settings `configuration` property as a whole:

```objc
UIButtonConfiguration *config = _mButton.configuration;
config.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
_mButton.configuration = config;
```